# frequency of occurring of a couple of variables

Tags: r, vector

I am using R.

I have a database that looks like this :

```
Price A       Price B   
1              3           
3              2            
1              3            
2              4          
3              2           
3              2            
3              3
```

What I would like to do is to count the number of occurence of each couple (Price A, Price B) and know which couples is the most prominent (let's say the three more prominent couples) and their frequency.

I really don't know how to do it.

For instance here:

(3,2) : 3 times

(1,3) : 2 times

(2,4) : 1 time

(3,3) : 1 time

Comment: Quick way coming to mind: `table(do.call(paste, your_df))`

Answer (score 1):

A `dplyr` possibility could be:

```
df %>%
 group_by_all() %>%
 tally()

  Price_A Price_B     n
    <int>   <int> <int>
1       1       3     2
2       2       4     1
3       3       2     3
4       3       3     1
```

Or the same result with `count()`:

```
df %>%
 count(Price_A, Price_B)
```

Or if you want the combinations of the two columns as one column:

```
df %>%
 mutate(Price_comb = paste(Price_A, Price_B, sep = ",")) %>%
 count(Price_comb) 

  Price_comb     n
  <chr>      <int>
1 1,3            2
2 2,4            1
3 3,2            3
4 3,3            1
```

Comment: and `df$price_comb = paste0(df$Price_A, df$Price_B` to get the combinations at once.

Comment: @Ronak Shah updated my post with this one, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

With base `R` : `df.new <- as.data.frame(with(df, table(Price.A, Price.B)))` or just `df.new <- as.data.frame(table(df))` as pointed out by @Ronak Shah

```
# output df.new
  Price.A Price.B Freq
1       1       2    0
2       2       2    0
3       3       2    3
4       1       3    2
5       2       3    0
6       3       3    1
7       1       4    0
8       2       4    1
9       3       4    0

df.new[df.new$Freq != 0, ]
#   Price.A Price.B Freq
3       3       2    3
4       1       3    2
6       3       3    1
8       2       4    1
```

**Data**

```
df <- structure(list(Price.A = c(1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L), Price.B = c(3L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 3L)), .Names = c("Price.A", "Price.B"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-7L))
```

Answer (score 0):

This can easily be done with a SQL query, so let's try using the `sqldf` package:

```
library(sqldf)

sql <- "SELECT price_a, price_b, COUNT(*) AS frequency
        FROM your_df
        GROUP BY price_a, price_b
        ORDER BY frequency DESC"

result <- sqldf(sql)
```

[image]

### Demo

Answer (score 0):

A different `tidyverse` way using `summarise` allowing you to specify the name of the new column.

Your data:

```
df <- structure(list(PriceA = c(1, 3, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3), PriceB = c(3, 
                                                             2, 3, 4, 2, 2, 3)), class = c("spec_tbl_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", 
                                                                                           "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -7L), spec = structure(list(
                                                                                             cols = list(PriceA = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
                                                                                                                                              "collector")), PriceB = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                  "collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        "collector")), skip = 2), class = "col_spec"))
```

Solution:

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
  group_by(PriceA, PriceB) %>% 
  summarise(Freq = n())

# A tibble: 4 x 3
# Groups:   PriceA [3]
  PriceA PriceB  Freq
   <dbl>  <dbl> <int>
1      1      3     2
2      2      4     1
3      3      2     3
4      3      3     1
```